# Grab instgram followercount via bash

Tags: bash, shell

Is it possible to create a script that outputs the Follower count of an instagram user of my choice?

I am trying to create a scraper, based on HTML source from http://www.imgrum.com. On the pages source are all things displayed i need beside the follower count of a page.

Do i have to use the APi to get the number of follows or is there any other way arround it.

How can i get this number? How can i integrate this in my bash script?

Answer (score 0):

You could use curl and something like:

```
curl -s "https://www.instagram.com/justinbieber/?hl=en" | sed -n 's/.*meta content=\"\(.*\) Followers.*$/\1/p'
```

We are pulling in the source code for a given page and then concentrating on printing the text signified by (.*) using sed.